# Bounds on the component group of the center of a reductive group arising as centralizer

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, centralisers

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $G$ be a reductive, but not necessarily connected, algebraic group over $k$. (For me: reductive group = no non-trivial connected normal unipotent subgroups.) Let $Z=Z(G)$ and $Z^\circ=Z(G)^\circ$ denote the center of $G$ and its identity component.

In the case where $G$ is connected, the order of the component group $Z/Z^\circ$ is bounded in terms of the root datum of $G$; namely, it is known that $Z^\circ$ coincides with the solvable radical of $G$ and that $Z/Z^\circ$ is the center of the semisimple group $G/Z^\circ$, and hence has order no greater than the order of the fundamental group of $G$, which is given in terms of the root datum of $G$ (this is explained, e.g., in chapter 9 of [1]).

However, if $G$ is disconnected, it may very well be that the radical contains $Z^\circ$ properly, in which case this type of argument would fail.

Assume now that $G=\mathrm{C}_H(g)$ where $H$ is a *connected* reductive group and $g\in H$ is *semisimple*. Let $Z$ and $Z^\circ$ be as above.

> **My Question**: Is there a way to bound the order of $Z/Z^\circ$ in terms of the root datum of $G^\circ$? Or of $H$?

**Edit**.  The original scope of the question was restricted following user YCor's comment.

---

[1] *Malle, Gunter; Testerman, Donna*, Linear groups and finite groups of Lie type., Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics 133. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-00854-0/hbk). xiv, 309 p. (2011). [ZBL1256.20045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1256.20045).

Comment: You can take $G=S\times F$ for an arbitrary finite abelian group $F$ (of order coprime to the characteristic) and given reductive $S$. For such a group $Z/Z^\circ$ contains $F$ and hence is arbitrary large. So you certainly want to put further restrictions.

Comment: @YCor certainly, you're correct. I forgot about this.. I changed the question to focus only on the case of disconnected centralizers. I don't know if I can actually give a more generalized setting..

Comment: OK it's fine (I don't think you need to emphasize negative assumptions such $G$ being disconnected, just say once that $G$ is not assumed connected). I guess what's important in your new assumption is being the centralizer of a semisimple element in a fixed connected reductive group.